# Determining the caster level for magic weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

In response to [a question about a melee rogue magic weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46221/what-is-this-magic-weapons-aura-and-cost/46306), I noticed I have a question myself about the requirement for creating magic items, or magic weapons in this case.

For an example, lets use a *+2 Frost Longsword*: it has a +2 enhancement and the [Frost](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#frost) special ability of an +1 equivalent cost.

When determining the crafter's minimal caster level for creating this magic weapon, [the rules say](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm):

> Creating a magic weapon has a special prerequisite: The creator’s caster level must be at least three times the enhancement bonus of the weapon. If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met.

How should interpret the '*enhancement bonus*' part here? Should I read it as:

- The weapon has a total enhancement bonus of +3, so the minimal caster level should be  9th (3×3).
- The weapon has a total enhancement bonus of +2, which gives a minimal caster level of 6th (3×2), but the *Frost* special ability has CL 8th, so the caster level for this weapon would be 8th.

Bonus points: where to find the rule?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It's Caster Level 8**

Your second interpretation is correct. [Here's the rule itself](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingMagicWeapons):

> Creating a magic weapon has a special prerequisite: The creator’s
>   caster level must be at least three times the enhancement bonus of the
>   weapon. If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability
>   the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met.

Then from the [Magic Weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm) page:

> In addition to an enhancement bonus, weapons may have special
>   abilities. Special abilities count as additional bonuses for
>   determining the market value of the item, but do not modify attack or
>   damage bonuses (except where specifically noted). A single weapon
>   cannot have a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability
>   bonus equivalents) higher than +10. A weapon with a special ability
>   must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.

From here, it's pretty clear that enhancement bonus and special abilities are distinct things. You combine them for the weapon cost (as the rule stats), but not for the crafting caster level requirement as each type has its own requirement. You just have to be able to meet all the requirements.

Thus, you need CL 6 (3x2) to make a +2 enhancement bonus, and CL 8 ([and have access to the spells Chill Metal or Ice Storm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#frost)) for *Frost*.

This also means all the weapons on the chart can be created without being epic level, as if you needed to be CL 9 to make your +2 Frost Weapon, it'd be impossible to do any combination that is >= +7 without epic levels. (You can't make a +7 sword without epic levels, but you can make a +5 *Keen Frost* one, which has the cost of a +7 equivalent weapon.)

**It Could Be Caster Level 6**

Depending on how you want to interpret the rules around prerequisites, you could create the weapon at CL 6 as a Druid (who get access to Chill Metal at level 3). The reason for that is these rule passages. [From the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm):

> While item creation costs are handled in detail below, note that
>   normally the two primary factors are the caster level of the creator
>   and the level of the spell or spells put into the item. A creator can
>   create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower
>   than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell.

And from DMG p. 215:

> For other items [besides potions, scrolls, and wands] the caster level
>   is determined by the creator. The minimum caster level is that which
>   is needed to meet the prerequisites given.

Depending on how you read this, the prerequisite could only be access to the spell itself, rather than the CL listed. In that case a level 6 Druid could create the item (as they can do both +2 and have access to a required spell).  A Sorceror would need to be level 8, as that's when they get access to Ice Storm.

I'm not 100% convinced this is how they intended it to work, but it makes an item entry like [Universal Solvent](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#universalSolvent) make a lot more sense. It has a listed CL of 20, which for such a common an inexpensive item just seems really wonky if only the greatest spellcasters on the planet are able to create it (particularly since the required spell is available to Wizards at level 9).

If you use this interpretation, the CL listed on the item entries is a guideline, or what you'd expect a normal item of it's type to be if you find one in the world.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a *+2 frost* weapon could be made at caster level 6 by a Drd6 employing the feat Craft Magic Arms and Armor and the spell *chill metal*. I don't know why the game assumes a Sor8 is making all the *frost* weapons, except, despite the effects and cost remaining the same, doing so decreases the weapon's ability to resist being affected by *dispel magic et al.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't think so, the rule says you need to meet the CL requirement and have access to the spell. You need to be CL 5 to create Merciful, and the spell for that is Cure Light Wounds.

Comment: Found it: "For other items [besides potions, scrolls, and wands] the caster level is determined by the creator. The minimum caster level is that which is needed to meet the prerequisites given" (*DMG* 215). Hence, a +2 *frost* weapon at CL 6 created by a Drd6 *is* possible, its just the game assumes CL 8 for *frost* weapons.

Comment: @HeyICanChan But wouldn't the CL listed there actually be a prerequisite? There's no reason whatsoever to list Merciful at CL 5, for example. The weapon rules say that you need to meet the caster level requirement specifically, as well. *If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met.*

Comment: Prerequisites differ from caster level. Look at, for example, the [*dwarven thrower*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#dwarvenThrower). The only reason to *create* a higher-level item is to resist or generate better effects.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Then why does it mention meeting the caster level *and* having access to the spell? If the CL doesn't matter, only having access to the spell would need to be mentioned at all.

Comment: The caster level *requirement* that's necessary for the weapon's creation isn't defined in the section you quoted but instead defined in the section I quoted on *DMG* 215. So, yeah, both CL requirements are necessary, but the *DMG* caster levels are suggestions--one needn't be a 20th-level caster to create, for example, [*universal solvent*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#universalSolvent), but the average *solvent* is created at that level.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, maybe add an answer to elaborate on why you think the caster level as described by the magical weapon special effect can be met with by a caster of a lower level?

Comment: @Monika I would, but I hesitate to as it's really just a gearhead nitpick footnote to Tridus's otherwise excellent answer, and I'd rather not distract from it.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Universal Solvent is CL 20? Okay, that's a pretty convincing example. I'll update.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, Tridus - I think you are missing something - the text (at least in the SRD) about CL states: "Caster Level for Weapons: **The caster level of a weapon with a special ability is given in the item description**. For an item with only an enhancement bonus and no other abilities, the caster level is three times the enhancement bonus. If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability, the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met." - So it seems this is *dictated* by the description, not *calculated* according to a crafter's access to the spell.

Comment: @G0BLiN So I had it right the first time and it is CL 8?

Comment: @G0BLiN That doesn't change *DMG* 215. *Yes*, the caster level of a weapon with a special ability is given in the item description. And *every* magic item has a caster level given in its description. That, however, isn't always the *minimum* caster level. Check [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#casterLevel).

Comment: @HeyICanChan *The prerequisites for creation of an item are given immediately following the item’s caster level.* That kind of gives it away, I think.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort put into the answer and the comments. I expected it to be just me, being ignorant of where the rules where written down.

Comment: @Tridus I can't tell if you're agreeing with me or if you're not. Yes, the prerequisites for creation of an item are given immediately following the item's caster level. That makes caster level *not* a prerequisite. Further, in the same section, "Typically, a list of prerequisites includes one feat and one or more spells (or some other requirement in addition to the feat)." A list doesn't *typically* include caster level (e.g. *dwarven thrower*).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am agreeing with you, sorry for the confusion. :)